# What sequences are in the $l^p$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to learn about the $l^p$ space for $1\leq p < \infty$. I have read some articles and such but I still don't have any kind of understanding about what sequences are in the $l^p$ space. Or what sequences aren't. Does anyone have a good way to explain this intuitively to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequences $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ in $l^p$ are those such that the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^p$$converges. All other sequences *don't* belong to $l^p$.

Comment: Does that mean that any sequences that don't absolutely converge would not be in $l^p$?

Comment: @Math4Life No, it does not. For instance, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ doesn't converge absolutely, but the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ belongs to $l^2$.

Comment: how is $\frac{1}{n}$ in $l^p$ if it doesn't converge?

Comment: @Math4Life What?! The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n\right)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges!

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

$\ell^p$ is a sequences space. A sequence in $\ell^p$ is a sequence of p-summable sequences.

More in detail,

$$\ell^p:=\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p<+\infty\}$$

This space is a normed space with the norm defined by

$$ \|x\|_p:=\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p<+\infty \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Observations:

- Every $(\ell^p,\|f\|_p)$ is a Banach space (complete normed space).
- $\ell^1$ is the space of sequences which have absolutely convergent series.
- Only $\ell^2$ is an Hilbert space (the norm $\|x\|_2$ is induced by an inner product).
- $\ell^\infty$ is the space of bounded sequences.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ell^p=\left\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\mid \sum_{n\geq 1}|x_n|^p<\infty \right\}.$$

Therefore if $p>1$ then $\left(\sqrt[p]\frac{1}{n}\right)_n\notin\ell^p$ and $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)_n\in \ell^p$.